# Compile c++ application standalone with Qt creator

Tags: c++, compilation, libraries, qmake, static-linking

I am new in the community and I would like to ask a question.
I have written an application in c++ with QT that I can compile and use on my linux distribution.
However, I cannot use the binary file on another computer which is normal because the libraries are different.
Using the ldd command on my aplication, I see that shared libraries are the following:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffee0fee000)
    libgvc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libgvc.so.6 (0x00007f2124aea000)
    libcgraph.so.6 => /usr/lib/libcgraph.so.6 (0x00007f21248d4000)
    libcdt.so.5 => /usr/lib/libcdt.so.5 (0x00007f21246cd000)
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 (0x00007f212445f000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f2123c2e000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f2123480000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f2122d46000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f2122ad4000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f21228b7000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2122535000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2122231000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f212201a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2121c7b000)
    libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f2121a71000)
    libxdot.so.4 => /usr/lib/libxdot.so.4 (0x00007f212186b000)
    libpathplan.so.4 => /usr/lib/libpathplan.so.4 (0x00007f2121663000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f2121439000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f212121f000)
    libicui18n.so.56 => /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007f2120d86000)
    libicuuc.so.56 => /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007f21209ce000)
    libicudata.so.56 => /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007f211efeb000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f211ede7000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f211ebe5000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f211e8d1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2125102000)
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f211e6ce000)
    libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f211e4cb000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f211e2c4000)
    libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f211e0c2000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f211de93000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f211dc81000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f211da7e000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f211d878000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f211d676000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f211d336000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f211d10e000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f211cef3000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f211ccee000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f211cae8000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f211c8d8000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f211c665000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f211c461000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f211c25b000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f211c045000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f211be3d000)
```

I would like to include these libraries in my application to be able to use it on another computer.

I don't know if i have to use it as static or shared and I do not care, I just want it works :).

I have tried adding them in my .pro file on QTcreator by the following way (examples with libgvc):

```
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/ -lgvc
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/lib
```

The compilation goes well. However, it still does not work on another computer like if libraries were not included in the binary file.

I also tried to add the following commands:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static
LIBS +=-Wl,-Bstatic
```

But in this case, I get an error message during compilation

```
Cannot find -lgvc
```

Do you have an idea of how I can compile my program as standalone on Linux with Qt creator?

Comment: Have you had a chance to read [Qt for Linux/X11 - Deployment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html)?

Comment: Are you cross-compiling from one computer to another? Is the architecture different? Is the OS different?

Comment: @IvanRubinson I doubt it.  The OP wants to create a single, standalone, executable that doesn't depend on any shared libraries.  His problem is that `gvc` is only available as a .so, not a .a file.

Comment: Did you consider shipping your source code to the target remote computer and build it there? BTW, you might not be legally allowed to link Qt statically (with its free software license)

Comment: I linked Qt and all libraries as shared libraries in a specific folder as explained in Ilya' s link. The idea is good to compile on the other computer. However I cant because it s a centos and a looooot of libraries are impossible to install on centos

Comment: Build gvc as a static library yourself. (I suspect it's only the first of many libraries you will have to build). Alternatively, https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container